# What are requirements for ConcurrencyStamp column in AspNetRoles?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm writing a data migration script that adds a record to the `AspNetRoles` table.

```
INSERT [dbo].[AspNetRoles] ([Id], [Name], [NormalizedName], [ConcurrencyStamp]) VALUES (N'c73c3117-51b4-4caa-80ed-379ca924e014', N'Manager', N'MANAGER', N'0d61dbe2-1e07-46e8-acd1-2a4610204a28')
```

For the `Id` value, I just generated a random GUID. But what about for the `ConcurrencyStamp` value? Can this also just be a random GUID?

I'm not clear on exactly how it's used. Do I need to do anything special here?

Answer (score 0):

No, so called row version columns are used by the ado.net system, and other client software (say ms-access for example).

So, these systems can use the row version for detection if the data been changed by someone else.

You as a developer thus never have to worry about, or in fact NEVER set such row version columns - they are for the data engine, and not your code. So, it is reasonable to state that you don't have to change such values, or worry about such values, and thus for a edit, or even an insert, that column should NOT be included in your update command.

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't asking if I need to change the value or update commands.

Comment: My advice stands: no, you as a developer never worry or include that column in your update or insert statements - it is a internal accounting system managed by the system, not your code. This allows .net to figure out if a record been changed, and thus avoids ado.net having to test all fields and columns. Without a row version, then a field by field compare will occur. Adding a row version means ado can now simple test the row version, and not revert to a field by field compare. However, as I stated, this is a internal system, and something the developer does not touch nor care about.

Comment: since the row version is a automatic internal system? No, you can't change how it works. If you are wondering, behind the scenes it is a simple long long integer value, and it increments by +1 each time a record is updated. But, to be clear, no, you can't change how it work or what it does - its internal managed by the database server. So, no, again, your code and SQL update statements don't have to be changed, and you don't include the row version in your code, nor ever try to change or update that row version "thing". Adopting row version does not change your code nor SQL statements.

Comment: I'm having difficult understand what you're talking about. Who said anything about changing how it works? Who said anything about update statements?

Comment: You posted a insert statement. I CLEARLY covered it don't matter if you doing a update or insert statement. So, yes, I 100% covered your question and use case of a insert statement, and I went on to expand that be it a insert statement or update statement - it does not matter. I suppose it possible that in your lifetime experience you ONLY EVER used a insert statement, but I would be shocked that information about both update or insert would not be relevant and valuable here. So both insert and update statements were covered in my answer, and both don't care, and you don't mess with rowverison

Comment: >>Can this also just be a random GUID?   (covered that case - answer = no).  >>I'm not clear on exactly how it's used. (I explained how it works - covered in my answer). >> Do I need to do anything special here? (covered in my answer - no you don't).

Comment: Yeah, well the last thing I would ever want to do is mess with these values or change the way it works. But looking at this column, I see it is nullable. So if I understand, you are saying that I can just leave it null when inserting.

Comment: Sure, on insert it might be null, but then again so is a plain jane identify column until the insert is done, and if the identifiy is also  a PK, it don't have to be nullable, but it still not going to have a value yet,, is it? So, once again, no, you don't care and don't mess with that column - just as I explained. but then again, it would seem you ONLY care and ever used a insert statement then? And are you asking that I limit this discussion and answer ONLY to a insert statement? (how selfish of you). Do you think it's possible that reading public here might want these relevant details?